# Prove that $((2k)!)^2+1 \equiv 0 \mod (4k+1)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $4k+1$ be a prime.
Prove that $((2k)!)^2+1 \equiv 0 \mod (4k+1)$.

I am having a hard time figuring this out. I see that
$$((2k)!)^2+1 \mod (4k+1)$$
$$\equiv (2k)!(2k)!+1 $$

I think I want to try and use wilson's theorem that $(4k)! \mod (4k+1) \equiv -1$ 
 but I am having trouble seeing how it works.

Comment: Wilsons theorem works for prime numbers only, so you can't use that to prove this for all $k$

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it is only for  k that give a prime.

Comment: I edited your post accordingly. Is this the question you meant?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: See Theorem 2.11 in Niven and Zuckerman on pages 24 and 25

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We know by Wilson's Theorem that, given that $4k+1$ is a prime,

$$(4k)!\equiv -1\mod 4k+1$$

Now see that (all $\mod 4k+1$):
\begin{align}
(4k)!&\equiv(4k)(4k-1)\cdots(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)(2k-1)\cdots2\cdot1\\
&\equiv-1\cdot-2\cdots(-2k+1)(-2k)(2k)(2k-1)\cdots2\cdot1\\
&\equiv(-1)^{2k}\cdot\left(1\cdot2\cdots(2k-1)(2k)\right)\left((2k)(2k-1)\cdots2\cdot1\right)\\
&\equiv1\cdot (2k)!\cdot(2k)!\\
&\equiv(2k)!^2\mod 4k+1
\end{align}

And so we arrive at $(2k)!^2+1\equiv0\mod 4k+1$, exactly as we wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate the help.